# Is the tensor product of a vector bundle with its dual bundle a trivial bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

I wonder if it's true, if it's true, is there a easy to see why it is true?

Comment: @6666 This is certainly true for line bundles. But if the vector bundle is a sum of line bundles say $L_1 \oplus L_2$ this is probably not true because then you would have to pair $L_1 \otimes L_2^{\vee}$ which does not have to be trivial.

Comment: I think this is only true for line bundles. It fails for the direct sum of two distinct line bundles.

Comment: @NAC that just gives you one section we need to find $n$ sections in general

Comment: Ok so my friends were wrong. It's true for line bundles but wrong for higher dimensions.

Comment: @happymath how to see it's true for line bundles?

Comment: @6666 A vector bundle is trivial if it has a non zero section. Can you see one such section?

Comment: @NAC sorry my bad. I wanted to say a line bundle is trivial if it has a non zero section

Comment: The name of this post should be "Is the endomorphism bundle trivial ?".

Comment: "A vector bundle is trivial if it has a non zero section."  This is *wrong*. A *line* bundle (i.e., a  1-dimensional bundle) is trivial if it has one nonzero section. But it's easy to find a 2-plane bundle over a circle S^1 that has one non-zero section without its being trivial. (The direct sum of a non-trivial line bundle over S^1 and a trivial line bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tensor product $E\otimes E^*$ of a vector bundle $E$ with its dual bundle $E^*$ is called the *endomorphism bundle* $\mathrm{End}(E)$. If you click $\rightarrow$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/271885) $\leftarrow$ there's an example of such a non trivial real endomorphism bundle.

**Answer :** no it's not true that *"the tensor product of a vector bundle with its dual bundle is a trivial bundle"*.

**Remarks :**

- Even though $\mathrm{End}(E)$ is generically non-trivial, $\mathrm{End}(E)$ admits a non-vanishing global section $\lambda$ given at each point $x$ of the base manifold $M$ by $\lambda|_x = \mathrm{id}_{E_x}$.
- There are special cases where $\mathrm {End}(E)$ is necessarily trivial. For example, if $E$ is a complex line bundle $L$, then the first Chern Class of $L\otimes L^*$ vanish and so $L\otimes L^*$ is trivial. Or again, since $L\otimes L^*$ has 1-dimensional fibers and has a non-vanishing global section then it is trivial.

Comment: Thank you, can you find a non-zero section?

Comment: @6666 Yes. At each point $x$ of the base manifold $M$, choose the identity of $E_x$. This gives a global non-vanishing section of $\mathrm{End}(E)$.

Comment: Thank you, but I wonder why this method can not be applied to the higher dimensional case, for example $E_x$ is a vector space of rank $n$, then we choose $(1,1...,1)$ ($n$ copies of $1$)

Comment: Yes the global section of $\mathrm{End}(E)$ I gave is for generic vector bundle $E$. I didn't assume it to be 1-dimensionnal.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I still have a naive question, how do you guarantee this section map you defined is continuous?

Comment: Indeed, to every line bundle, you can define such a map by " At each point $x$ of the base manifold $M$, choose the identity of $E_x$" but it may not always be a section, I wonder it works in this case.

Comment: The first remark may not be correct since line bundles are trivial iff there is a non-zero section

Comment: The first remark is correct. I wrote "generically", not "always".

Comment: The identity section can be built from the constant map with identity matrix value on the frame bundle of $E$. You can check it is equivariant for the corresponding representation.